# Not able to get top Score or Player Score from Leaderboard through "PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores" in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I am using following code to get top score:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores ("Leaderboard_id", 
LeaderboardStart.TopScores,1, LeaderboardCollection.Public , 
LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime, (LeaderboardScoreData data) => {   

        if(data.Valid){
            hScore = (int)data.Scores[0].value;
            HScore.text = hScore.ToString();
        } else{             
        }
    });
```

This returns me 0. Please help me if i am doing anything wrong or missing on anything. I have searched for this on multiple threads but haven't find any solution. Please help with this if anyone can

Comment: Is your Leaderboard ID value equals to "Leaderboard_id"? Please see this related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258240/unity3d-googleplayservices-and-playgamesplatform-instance-loadscores-cant-wr

Comment: Are you positive that there is an actual top score (> 0) to be retrieved? Have you tried retrieving more than 1 row and see if those have values?

Comment: @Levon Thanks for response. Yeah i am using exact string for leaderboard id which i have got from playstore.

Comment: @AL. Yes there are multiple score (>0) and yes i have tried to get more than 1 rows as well but no luck with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here my code, it's working fine.

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores (
 LeaderboardID,
 LeaderboardStart.TopScores,
 1,
 LeaderboardCollection.Public,
 LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
 (LeaderboardScoreData data) => {
    topScore = (int) data.Scores[0].value;
    topScoreTextBox.text = topScore.ToString();
});
```

First of all Initialize PlayGamesPlatform

```
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
```

Then activate the Google Play Games platform

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

Then check user is LoggedIn

```
if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
```

If user LoggedIn Then call LoadScores. Hope you will get your leaderboard top score.